# Error fetching data with Axios in NextJS and Strapi

Tags: next.js, axios, strapi

Thanks in advance for helping me figure this out. What I did:

- Deployed Strapi Project
- Deployed NextJs project
- Installed and setup Axios to fetch data from strapi backend

but continue getting this error:

```
import axios from "axios"  //axios is installed.

const DashboardHome = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL;  // url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/users'

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/users`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FORGEDMART_STRAPI_API_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      {...}
    },
  };
}
```

```
//Error
AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337 {
  port: 1337,
  address: '::1',
  errno: -61,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Authorization: 'bearer udududhdhdhdhd83838383',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.1.3',
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/users',
    data: undefined
  },
```

Comment: Is it on deployed poject? Then you can't use `http://localhost:1337` there should be some domain routing, ideally something like `https://api.example.com`

Comment: @antokhio - No it's not yet deployed, still in dev

Comment: `::1:1337` this also may mean you are using ipv6 for some reason, try put there your ip address like `http://192.168.1.10:1337/`